# GST 10% flat on all item in magento

Tags: magento

i want to add 10% on cart and also include on shipping price .
meance one item have 100$ and shipping price is 10$ , 
then final price is 
100+10=110*10% =  121$ final price.

i know there are option for tax calculation , but not sure for shipping price include in tax.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it from  adminside sales->tax->managetaxrules

You can add your own tax rule here.
also this rules you can get from google.

Answer (score 1):

sales->tax->managetaxrules
You can add you tax.